# Determine whether factor levels across columns match in R

Tags: r

I am trying to make a new variable in R (3.3.2) by checking whether the levels of a factor in multiple columns are the same across rows.

```
id<-c(1:5)
X1<-c("species1", "species1", NA, "species1", "species1")
X2<-c(NA, "species2", NA, "species2", "species2")
X3<-c("species1", "species2", "species2", "species3", "species3")
```

It should look like this, checking whether X1:X3 are all the same (ignoring NAs):

```
     id  X1         X2         X3         same   
[1,] 1   "species1" NA         "species1" TRUE 
[2,] 2   "species1" "species2" "species2" FALSE
[3,] 3   NA         NA         "species2" TRUE
[4,] 4   "species1" "species2" "species3" FALSE
[5,] 5   "species1" "species2" "species3" FALSE
```

EDIT: here is my actual data, and the code I used from @Mike's answer below:

```
s$same <- apply(s[,c(2:11)], 1, function(x) length(unique((x[!is.na(x)]))) == 1)

dput(droplevels(head(s)))

structure(list(rowid = structure(c(5L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("-68975029755346725", 
"-6985608891139937154", "-7064257681237955764", "-716653329714258929", 
"-7190954401213249258", "-7190954401427629087"), class = "factor"), 
    species1 = structure(c(3L, NA, 3L, 1L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("Mycobacterium avium complex", 
    "Mycobacterium fortuitum", "Mycobacterium kansasii"), class = "factor"), 
    species2 = structure(c(NA, NA, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c(" Mycobacterium fortuitum", 
    "Mycobacterium avium complex", "Mycobacterium fortuitum", 
    "Mycobacterium kansasii"), class = "factor"), species3 = structure(c(4L, 
    NA, 3L, 1L, 2L, NA), .Label = c(" Mycobacterium avium complex", 
    " Mycobacterium fortuitum", " Mycobacterium kansasii", "Mycobacterium kansasii"
    ), class = "factor"), species4 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 1L), .Label = " Mycobacterium fortuitum", class = "factor"), 
    species5 = structure(c(1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = "Mycobacterium kansasii", class = "factor"), 
    species6 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), .Label = " Mycobacterium fortuitum", class = "factor"), 
    species7 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = character(0), class = "factor"), 
    species8 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = character(0), class = "factor"), 
    species9 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = character(0), class = "factor"), 
    species10 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = character(0), class = "factor"), 
    same = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)), .Names = c("rowid", 
"species1", "species2", "species3", "species4", "species5", "species6", 
"species7", "species8", "species9", "species10", "same"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Row 1 and 6 are correct, but they should **all** be true among this group.

I've tried `apply` and `ifelse` with every combination of `all`, `identical`, `duplicated`, and `unique` I can think of, but either you can't use `na.rm` with the function or I get a matrix output instead of a new variable. There seem to be many questions doing this with numerical variables, but I'm having trouble finding what I need with a factor or string variable. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `same` should be `TRUE` when what variables are matched? Because in your example 3 is `TRUE` but there is not match.

Comment: Shouldn't 2 also be `TRUE`, given that X2 and X3 match?

Comment: I want to match across X1:X3. I see what you mean about 3, but I'd just like "same" to be "TRUE" in that case. The reason I am doing this is that I need to see which rows all had the same species and which had multiple species for later characterization.

Comment: @Yannis, no, because X1 is different. I need all to match (ignoring NA), not any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `length` and `unique` to check that there is only 1 unique value?

```
df <- data.frame(id = id, X1 = X1, X2 = X2, X3 = X3)
df$same <- apply(df[,c("X1","X2","X3")], 1, function(x) 
                length(unique(trimws(x[!is.na(x)]))) == 1 | length(unique(trimws(x))) == 1)

df
#  id       X1       X2       X3  same
# 1  1 species1     <NA> species1  TRUE
# 2  2 species1 species2 species2 FALSE
# 3  3     <NA>     <NA> species2  TRUE
# 4  4 species1 species2 species3 FALSE
# 5  5 species1 species2 species3 FALSE
```

Added in `trimws()` to get rid of leading/trailing blanks and condition where all are `NA`.

Comment: For some reason when I run that, the NAs seem to still be counting and I'm getting "FALSE" for those rows... And I've double checked to make sure they are in fact NA and not blank or something else.

Comment: I actually have 10 variables (it's a very large dataset), but I'm pretty sure that I've called them correctly into the function.

Comment: @ericotta @Mike H's code works. The problem is that you have leading spaces in your character vectors, so `"Mycobacterium avium complex" == " Mycobacterium avium complex"` will return `FALSE`